# How to filter\search all read receipt in outlook-web-access then delete all of them?

Tags: outlook-web-access

How do I filter\search all read receipt in outlook-web-access then delete all of them?

All of them are in my inbox.

Version: 14.3.399.0

Client Access server version: 14.3.123.0

Mailbox server Microsoft Exchange version: 14.3.123.0

Comment: What OWA version do you use (Office 365/Exchange...)?

Comment: @thims question edited.

Answer (score 0):

Make a rule for it:

1) Go to **settings** popup

2) Choose **Rules** tab right to **Email** tab and **Add new rule**

3) Type in a name for the rule

4) Add the condition **Type**: **Read Receipt**

5) Add the action **Delete**

Note: my outlook is in portuguese, so the english wording might not be exactly like I wrote here.